# Selecting coefficients of multivariable polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

We have polynomial in three variables `x, y, z`.

How to list all coefficients of odd powers of `z` or `y` and any power of `x`?

Red are coefficients  of `z y^(2n)` or `z^3 y^(2n)`.

Green are coefficients of `y z^(2n)` or `y^3 z^(2n)`.

Yellow are coefficients of `z^3 y` or `z y^3` or `z y` (or `z^3 y^3` though there are not any).

```
Collect[(a1 x + a2 y + a3 z)^4 + (b1 x + b2 y + b3 z)^4 + (c1 x + 
    c2 y + c3 z)^4, {z, y, x}, Factor]
```

[image]

I can do it by selecting parts of `CoefficientList` and the parts defined manually.

I can automatize creation of the list of parts but the code would be cumbersome and hard to read.

I would prefer a code that it would be evident what the code is doing at the first glance.

From my code it is not evident that it selects coefficients of odd powers of `z, y`.

```
DeleteCases[
  CoefficientList[(a1 x + a2 y + a3 z)^4 + (b1 x + b2 y + 
          b3 z)^4 + (c1 x + c2 y + c3 z)^4, {z, y, 
        x}][[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2,
       3}, {2, 4}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}} // 
   Flatten, 0] // Factor

(* {4 (a1^3 a2 + b1^3 b2 + c1^3 c2), 
 4 (a1 a2^3 + b1 b2^3 + c1 c2^3), 4 (a1^3 a3 + b1^3 b3 + c1^3 c3), 
 12 (a1^2 a2 a3 + b1^2 b2 b3 + c1^2 c2 c3), 
 12 (a1 a2^2 a3 + b1 b2^2 b3 + c1 c2^2 c3), 
 4 (a2^3 a3 + b2^3 b3 + c2^3 c3), 
 12 (a1 a2 a3^2 + b1 b2 b3^2 + c1 c2 c3^2), 
 4 (a1 a3^3 + b1 b3^3 + c1 c3^3), 4 (a2 a3^3 + b2 b3^3 + c2 c3^3)} *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution with `CoefficientRules`. The code is easy to read since we immediately see selection is done by `OddQ` on the first two (`{1,2}`) variables, i.e. `z, y`.

```
CoefficientRules[(a1 x + a2 y + a3 z)^4 + (b1 x + b2 y + 
     b3 z)^4 + (c1 x + c2 y + c3 z)^4, {z, y, x}];
Select[%, Or @@ OddQ@#[[1, {1, 2}]] &][[All, 2]]
```

Comment: +1 Do you not need to keep the associated powers of `y` and `z` to know what is what?

Comment: No, coefficients can be in any order, but with `CoefficientRules` you can keep also associations if needed.

Answer (score 2):

We can create a function called `SelectMonomials` with the option to retrieve the coefficients:

```
SelectMonomials[pol_, vars_?VectorQ, cond_, 
type : (Automatic | "ToCoefficientList") : Automatic] /; 
PolynomialQ[pol, vars] := 
Switch[type, Automatic, Select[MonomialList[pol // Expand, vars], cond], 
"ToCoefficientList", ReplaceAll[Thread[vars -> 1]][
Select[MonomialList[pol // Expand, vars], cond]]]
```

Testing `SelectMonomials`:

```
pol = (a1 x + a2 y + a3 z)^4 + (b1 x + b2 y + b3 z)^4 + (c1 x + c2 y + c3 z)^4;

SelectMonomials[pol, {x, y, z}, OddQ[Exponent[#, y]] || OddQ[Exponent[#, z]] &]
```

[image]

Using the optional argument "ToCoefficientList":

```
SelectMonomials[pol, {x, y, z}, OddQ[Exponent[#, y]] || OddQ[Exponent[#, z]] &, "ToCoefficientList"]
```

[image]

I hope you will find it useful!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to first get rid of the terms that you do not need:

```
lstZ = z^(2 #) -> 0 & /@ Range[2]
lstY = y^(2 #) -> 0 & /@ Range[2]

(*  {z^2 -> 0, z^4 -> 0}

{y^2 -> 0, y^4 -> 0}  *)

poly2 = (poly // Expand) /. lstZ /. lstY

(* a1^4 x^4 + b1^4 x^4 + c1^4 x^4 + 4 a1^3 a2 x^3 y + 4 b1^3 b2 x^3 y + 
 4 c1^3 c2 x^3 y + 4 a1 a2^3 x y^3 + 4 b1 b2^3 x y^3 + 
 4 c1 c2^3 x y^3 + 4 a1^3 a3 x^3 z + 4 b1^3 b3 x^3 z + 
 4 c1^3 c3 x^3 z + 12 a1^2 a2 a3 x^2 y z + 12 b1^2 b2 b3 x^2 y z + 
 12 c1^2 c2 c3 x^2 y z + 4 a2^3 a3 y^3 z + 4 b2^3 b3 y^3 z + 
 4 c2^3 c3 y^3 z + 4 a1 a3^3 x z^3 + 4 b1 b3^3 x z^3 + 
 4 c1 c3^3 x z^3 + 4 a2 a3^3 y z^3 + 4 b2 b3^3 y z^3 + 4 c2 c3^3 y z^3  *)
```

Now:

```
lst1 = Table[y^(2 n + 1), {n, 0, 2}];
lst2 = Table[z^(2 n + 1), {n, 0, 2}];
lst3 = {y*z, y*z^2, y*z^3, y^2*z, y^3*z};
```

and

```
Coefficient[poly2, #] & /@ lst2 /. y -> 0

(*  {4 a1^3 a3 x^3 + 4 b1^3 b3 x^3 + 4 c1^3 c3 x^3, 
 4 a1 a3^3 x + 4 b1 b3^3 x + 4 c1 c3^3 x, 0}  *)

Coefficient[poly2, #] & /@ lst1 /. z -> 0

(* {4 a1^3 a2 x^3 + 4 b1^3 b2 x^3 + 4 c1^3 c2 x^3, 
 4 a1 a2^3 x + 4 b1 b2^3 x + 4 c1 c2^3 x, 0}  *)

Coefficient[poly2, #] & /@ lst3

(*  {12 a1^2 a2 a3 x^2 + 12 b1^2 b2 b3 x^2 + 12 c1^2 c2 c3 x^2, 0, 
 4 a2 a3^3 + 4 b2 b3^3 + 4 c2 c3^3, 0, 
 4 a2^3 a3 + 4 b2^3 b3 + 4 c2^3 c3}  *)
```

Hope I understood you right, and this is what you need.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution, see my answer. There are `9` coefficients that fulfill conditions, it seems you missed one. And from the code it is not evident what it is doing.

Comment: @azerbajdzan My task is only to point a direction of solving the problem. Details and subtleties are already up to you. After all it is your problem, not mine.